# Como sumar renglones de una matriz en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas amigos de la comunidad. Soy nuevo en esto de las matrices, lo que quiero es sumar los valores verticales de una matriz, por ejemplo

[1][5]

[1][5]

[1][5]

Resultado

[3][15]

Tengo mi código que sirve para llenar la matriz, pero no tengo idea de cómo hacer que se sumen de manera vertical, espero me puedan ayudar, que tengan un buen día.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int c=0;
    int r=0;
    int aux=0;
    cout<<"Digite las Renglones"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"Digite las Columnas"<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    int m[r][c];

    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<r; j++){
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
            cin>>m[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Proceso: "<<endl;

    for(int x=0; x<c; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<r; y++) {
            cout << "[" << m[x][y] << "]";
            }
        cout<<endl;
        }







    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No puedes crear un array en tiempo de ejecución. No es parte del estandar y puedes obtener errores.

Comment: Que me sugieres entonces amigo @user3733164

Comment: ¿Habéis mirado la memoria dinámica? Es la forma de crear arrays en tiempo de ejecución. http://conclase.net/c/curso/cap17

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que para definir arrays en tiempo de ejecución no puedes hacerlo como lo haces, sino que has de utilizar memoria dinámica [a través de punteros](http://conclase.net/c/curso/cap17). Como es un array bidimensional lo que quieres, habrás de definir un puntero a puntero:
Algo así:

```
int **m;
```

Esto te permitirá crear un array de punteros, los cuales se usarán a su vez para reservar la memoria necesaria por cada elemento.

```
int **m;    
m = new int*[filas];

for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
{
    m[i] = new int[columnas];
}
```

Por otro lado, esta memoria dinámica hay que liberarla al acabar el programa:

```
for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
{
    delete[] m[i];
}
delete[] m;
```

Una vez aclarado esto, yo sugiero crear un array auxiliar, unidimensional, con tantos elementos como columnas tenga tu array. Y en el momento del llenado de datos, que vaya sumando los elementos de cada columna. Como hemos dicho, este array también se creará usando memoria dinámica:

```
int* sumas;
sumas = new int[columnas];
```

Y también habrá que liberar su memoria al final:

```
delete[] sumas;
```

Y como comentaba, en el momento de ingresar los datos es cuando se puede ir añadiendo cada elemento al array de sumas:

```
for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
            cin>>m[i][j];
            sumas[j]+=m[i][j];//nueva linea para sumar 
        }
    }
```

Ahora que tenemos todas las piezas, este puede ser el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int filas=0;
    int columnas=0;
    int aux=0;
    cout<<"Digite las Renglones"<<endl;
    cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite las Columnas"<<endl;
    cin>>columnas;
    int **m;
    int* sumas;
    sumas = new int[columnas];
    for (int i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        sumas[i]=0;
    }

    m = new int*[filas];
    // n arrays de m ints
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        m[i] = new int[columnas];

    for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
            cin>>m[i][j];
            sumas[j]+=m[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Proceso: "<<endl;

    for(int x=0; x<filas; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<columnas; y++)
        {
            cout << "[" << m[x][y] << "]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //mosrtar resultado
    for (int i=0;i<columnas;i++)
    {
        cout<<"["<<sumas[i]<<"]";
    }
    //borrar memoria dinamica
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    {
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    delete[] m;
    delete[] sumas;

    return 0;
}
```

P.D. Acostúmbrate a usar nombres más descriptivos para las variables. Cuanto más legible sea el código más fácil es de leer y entender. Saludos

Comment: Pero quien te dijo eso, porque ese enredo, de dondr sacas eso de que el usuario esta creando una matriz en tiempo de ejecucion, revisa bien creo que no estas claro en lo que dices

Comment: Parece que el tamaño de la matriz se define en tiempo de ejecución, luego no es posible crear un VLA en C++ (solo en el estabndar C99) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: A ver, el no esta declarando ninguna matriz dinamicamente, lo que pasa es que el no le da valores a r y a c, los deja en cero, cuando deberia poner por ejemplo r = 3 y c=8, a el no le hace falta declarar ninguna matriz dinamica no es el caso

Comment: Las inicializa a 0 -lo que es una buena costumbre- pero les asigna un valor en el momento de la ejecución mediante `cin`, y cuando tiene los valores de  `c` y `r` crea el array. Mírate el enlace que le pongo.

Comment: Estas confundido, el no crea nada dinámicamente, prueba mi código para que veas, el lo que hace es darle el tamaño a la matriz con los datos que entra para c y r, eso es lo mismo que inicializar a r y c con un valor

Comment: @Japv el usuario está creando una matriz en tiempo de ejecución en la 11ª línea del código que publica.

Comment: Si ya me di cuenta de lo que dicen, mis disculpas, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, en C++ las formaciones<sup>1</sup> declaradas en memoria estática deben ser de tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, es decir: no puedes leer dos variables y usar esas variables como tamaño para la formación:

```
int c=0;
int r=0;

cout<<"Digite las Renglones"<<endl;
cin>>c;
cout<<"Digite las Columnas"<<endl;
cin>>r;
int m[r][c]; // Incumple las normas de C++
```

Eso que haces se conoce como *formación de tamaño variable* (FTV) y no está soportado por el estándar de C++, salvo en extensiones del compilador, esto significa que ese código puede no compilar en otros compiladores o puede tener comportamientos inesperados.

En lugar de FTV puedes usar vectores:

```
int c=0;
int r=0;

cout<<"Digite las Renglones"<<endl;
cin>>r;
cout<<"Digite las Columnas"<<endl;
cin>>c;

using renglon = std::vector<int>;
using matriz = std::vector<renglon>;

matriz m(r, renglon(c, 0)); // matriz de 'r' renglones con 'c' columnas cada renglón
```

Teniendo esto, necesitarás dónde almacenar la suma de cada columna, puedes guardarlo en un nuevo renglón:

```
renglon resultado(c, 0); // Renglon de 'c' columnas

for (const auto &f : m)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna != f.size(); ++columna)
    {
        cout << f[columna] << ' ';
        resultado[columna] += f[columna];
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

for (const auto &v : resultado)
    cout << v << ' ';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHNTsQgFIXX5SmuY2LbzOiMGjeWstGtG7fqglDakLQwAdrFTObZK5T@aWbRFO453PNxYcfjPauprPr@VkhWtwUHLJSxmtOGoKXWcWaVJggJaaGhQiYpOqOoNUJWIGnDzZEyDsYWGUKRN7H8kIWV9isUMdVajDfvohKWQ00NfHJZ1Upys8GYy6J2fiYkITq75n5TddtI@t/MfO/AoUM/yCHgYpdOskltqNXitIijm/jzo9Ykejd1SdgODmmawX4PH0F2g4h1PBm4AebCYha7f0ADRgsKrVSuZak0JLS1Cu5KeIUmRdG61rla6Wv@FkAIdJ5juoHmpq0tLVSgGCDGaQ0Uq8wpyrEYC38Dz1Pm8CDhgBvAIZs3NzmUD0aceOJCttux7LnOA5t7BcAYyq9R@fG7GOLMqzPlom7zldebLmjpEn9Lf/ByDdnPY@6Xrg51c6Ifj221dPzo0vfP6Ak9opf5@wU)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.